# Why do Kotlin-specific dependencies exist for Android

Tags: android, kotlin

I notice that Android often offers two different dependency libraries that provide the same functionality. For example:

```
implementation 'androidx.preference:preference:1.1.1'
implementation 'androidx.preference:preference-ktx:1.1.1'
```

But if I'm developing an Android app using Kotlin, it expects me to use the Kotlin dependency. Why is this? What's special about the Kotlin library?

Comment: ktx is for kotlin, which is compatible with this language.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You ask:

> What's special about the Kotlin library?

Well,

> Android KTX is a set of Kotlin extensions that are included
> with Android Jetpack and other Android libraries

more info [here](https://developer.android.com/kotlin/ktx)

These extension methods and other useful functionality usually just makes other tedious tasks a bit simpler OR it makes it a bit more concise by using Kotlin capabilities to achieve something, consider them additional utility methods which help you to write a bit more concise Kotlin code, but you don't have to use this specifically, no